# How to create an "after deploy" command with Symfony2

Tags: shell, symfony, command

I need to create a command that execute:

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
$ php app/console composer:update
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:create
$ php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load .... yes
$ php app/console assets:dump --env=prod
```

Have you any idea? (I have tried Capifony for deploy process, but it is not the purpose of this new task).

Thanks.

Comment: What about creating an alias that performs all these lines? `alias my_things="php app/console cache:clear ...; php app/console composer:...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on a Unix/Linux like system ? If yes you can put them all in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
dir="path where Symfony is installed"
cd "$dir"
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
php app/console composer:update
php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load .... yes
php app/console assets:dump --env=prod
```

Comment: symfony suggests not to use `php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force` in production environment.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Answer (score 3):

If you use Composer, you can add some post-install commands in the "scripts" section of the composer.json file, for example (this is one from standard symfony distribution):

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

try to install a console bundle look at this https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle 
This bundle allows you accessing the Symfony2 console via your browser